# self.sendLine or self.transport.write?

Tags: python, twisted

In twisted, what is the difference between calling self.transport.write () and self.sendLine () ?
For example, the following program behaves identically whatever I call in the lineReceived 
method :

```
class FooProtocol(basic.LineReceiver):

    delimiter = '\n'

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("Foo")

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.sendLine("Echoed: " + line)
        #self.transport.write("Echoed: " + line + "\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stdio.StandardIO(FooProtocol())
    reactor.run()
```

Is there a more pythonic (or twistedic ...) way of doing this ?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`sendLine()`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-12.2.0/twisted/protocols/basic.py#L618) is a convience method. The default implementation is:

```
def sendLine(self, line):
    return self.transport.write(line + self.delimiter)
```

`sendLine()` is a slightly higher-level function. You don't need to use `self.transport.write()` directly in a line-oriented protocol.

Comment: Thanks J.F.Sebastian for your reply. May be it is better to use sendLine instead of accessing the transport attribute ? (I am new to python ... don't know if what I write makes sense ...)